# Type 'MyDto' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have a class that serves as a DTO

```
export class MyDto {
    name: string
    age: number
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
      this.name = name
      this.age = age
    }
}
```

And then I have an abstract class

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>> {
  constructor(public readonly title: string, public readonly data: T) {}
}
```

And another class that extends the abstract class and passes in `MyDto` as the Generic Type as seen:

```
class MyChildClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyDto> {
  constructor(data: MyDto) {
    super('user_info', data)
  }
}
```

But I'm getting a typing error that `Type 'MyDto' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, unknown>'.`

I have a function that is expecting an argument that's got a type of `MyAbstractClass` like so:

```
function useClass(data: MyAbstractClass) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

If I pass an instance of `MyChildClass` into `useClass` like so:

```
const instance = new MyChildClass(new MyDto('John', 17))
useClass(instance)
```

I get another type error: `Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'MyDto'.`

I'm still working my way through Typescript generics and not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Please [edit] and ensure your code is a [mre] without errors unrelated to your question.  You have curly braces around your constructor parameters; I assume that's just a typo.  Once you do that, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMzx1W) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks. I have made edits to the code and narrowed the error to the exact point it's happening. The error is specifically happening where I use the instance.

Comment: Your issue is that class instance types don't get implicit index signatures, so they will not be assignable to `Record<string, unknown>`.  The fix depends on your use case.  Why are you using `Record<string, unknown>`?  You should probably be using `object` instead as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPg7zm).  Does that fix your issue or do you have some use case for `Record<string, unknown>` you can articulate?

Comment: This is a new codebase I'm just getting into and I'm not entirely sure why `Record<string, unknown>` was used. I tried using `object` before now but I needed to be sure that was not some hacky solution I was coming up with first. Your explanation gives me a good argument and understanding to help me ask an informed question about the chosen type used here to other engineers working on the codebase. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is for a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter to be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to an object type (that is, a non-primitive type), then you should use [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) instead of `Record<string, unknown>`:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<T extends object = object> {
  constructor(
    public readonly title: string,
    public readonly data: T
  ) { }
}    

class MyChildClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyDto> { // okay
  constructor(data: MyDto) {
    super('user_info', data)
  }
}
    
function useClass(data: MyAbstractClass) {}        
const instance = new MyChildClass(new MyDto('John', 17))
useClass(instance) // okay
```

Why is `Record<string, unknown>` not a good idea here?

---

The type `Record<string, unknown>` using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) is equivalent to `{[k: string]: unknown}`, an object type with a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

You are often allowed to assign objects without index signatures to `Record<string, unknown>`, because such object types will be given [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures):

```
type UnknownDict = { [k: string]: unknown };

const anonObjectType = { a: "abc" };
const thisOneWorks: UnknownDict = anonObjectType; // okay

type TypeAliasToObjType = { a: string };
const typeAliasToObjType: TypeAliasToObjType = { a: "abc" };
const thisOneAlsoWorks: UnknownDict = typeAliasToObjType; // okay
```

But for better or worse, [`interface` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) as well as [`class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) instance types without index signatures are *not* given implicit index signatures, and therefore not considered assignable to object types with index signatures:

```
interface Interface { a: string }
const iface: Interface = { a: "abc" };
const nope: UnknownDict = iface; // error
// Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Interface'.

class Class { a = "abc" };
const stillNope: UnknownDict = new Class(); // error
// Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Class'.

type TypeAliasToInterface = Interface;
const typeAliasToInterface: TypeAliasToInterface = { a: "abc" };
const nopeAgain: UnknownDict = typeAliasToInterface; // error
// Type 'Interface' is not assignable to type 'UnknownDict'.
```

This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) in which it is stated that this difference is intentional, and which was recently closed and locked with the [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-1320620897)

> interfaces should declare an explicit index signature if they intend to be indexed.

So by writing `extends Record<string, unknown>`, you're essentially prohibiting most interfaces and classes from being assignable to it, unless you go into them and explicitly add an index signature to them.  Which you *could* do if you want:

```
export class MyDto {
  name: string
  age: number
  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  }
  [k: string]: unknown; // <-- add an index signature here
}

abstract class MyAbstractClass<
  T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>
> {
  constructor(
    public readonly title: string,
    public readonly data: T
  ) { }
}


class MyChildClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyDto> { // okay
  constructor(data: MyDto) {
    super('user_info', data)
  }
}

function useClass(data: MyAbstractClass) {}        
const instance = new MyChildClass(new MyDto('John', 17))
useClass(instance) // okay
```

but I doubt you really want to enforce such a restriction.

---

The right type to use is `object`.  Note that in the past the [`@typescript-eslint/ban-types`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) linting rule used to [warn](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/d3587857227526594f05a1d96515afe3c2ee0545/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules/ban-types.ts#L101-L102) that `object` was hard to use and should be replaced with `Record<string, unknown>`. [This was, in my opinion, bad advice](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732#issuecomment-886221640), especially when used in generic constraints like `T extends object`. But regardless, [it is no longer discouraged by that rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/6079).  The `object` type is not banned; feel free to use it.  And if someone tells you that you can't use `object` and you should use `Record<string, unknown>` instead, make sure that they have some reason that isn't just this outdated (and misguided) advice.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgPIBGAVhPAC4AqAnjMgYUUhAB4wB7AE4Mk8DCChQkAWRYARBgLxduxcBABcSKAyEBLYAHNV3EEa3EArmCoQhpovAHBdQq42EAKEpbeGjABokc0tgGzshAEoVNTUGAAt9KAA6XyQAXnVIR25E5JTQzJCLXIBfUwrTECo3BFFxSWk5AEFavXqAYQkpAB4mHl4GCGAAE2kBWnpRLMm6RgA+WLjnVz0PJSEvXKIYKyoMfXgkIQgQUZcMFiQGfQYMPz0AwJ2kPYOjk7OL4CukUZADBA2iYuRiuCQFTUVVMjSkshYnSSGFG3Sag2GY2aLDadUYaL6ckUAiWEIA9GSkAIANYgFi5VZuDbeAFA7REpTg15QKzsLYAcisUHsAH1DAAzAT84KskBRcqVfBKtTiqzARj6FxIIUQAlQLyy9k49pCLo9KBcuJiFxQAQPFIYARGA2AuWK5XcRmiQy6EDq5BZYAQADuCKR+hRep8IYRxK8-JQAgSwGlSAAjAB2KLytQ6qM+oH+mIUqm0+lEGFEXxkRBIACSYBgh3gdzrYz48ggYGUnHibGQAFVgNTgAJg8B5EcZngkABtanafzGAC62jVI7HwEhAG4PU4baI-S5qPNmP3ihDgUgAEQ1eDXnewg83JJQChBgDqwmpUG0Q4346TowxRHsAJ7TKw7DbkgJY0nSe43OekEQC0hySEwAgnshF4hIuTzGI+aheoh7Cofo6GYbQyEgv2ZEUVh55ZJe2i3lQ96EZ6z75G+QaobaX5CD+f7DqOgFTsUDC0WhUAYQxUEwZScH0qYhjDEI4rkPWwBqRptbMTo+FGJCT5rEg+i6ZYbY6ZpTG4Ted4PmUu5Ec+o7sMJAETuJWTmeQ0ElvYQjCKYJZtqMfA6PoRigAwVinEgkpCCRyD8kuRj8mZ0hgMkUABGZW6SewSD8lZ9gWfyKQIXC0h6jOIDFKx7FOSZugGRGGAAHICO5SD-qJXnAYGMZRlE-mUoFwVqKF7a8JF0WAnFyCJclxVpRlyRINlUh5YYK38nqFUIYVyDIXRMkCKV6k2Vp1mIM5nGmcdZ0YZdFk0aR0kvdpZXXfpjWOfd+6mW5KFGCAhgef1QHTk9n0Xd9V13QpPBCEFDhTZS2ElQj5WZcQAiHtt80HMgSh7X1m7Q4dXBQtk0BwLWYV8AAylFMWLSoph8IIIhiOasZkwQVq+HhBjGLkoTaOEtj2AyB7uJ4WwiwZYtBCUYQRPYlpWi+BTpIGGivNxhQWCBpRWrTajzqLASrtqImbmNSC9AAtC7ISjKMIRboY4Wzbl82xfFCT2BA7pqDUeINPzrQmmaTT9BiIzjEgABK9DCKMvRpcE679UsWTp84QhZzn9ueQspJy2sCubNsOtvPszZfOclzXLc9yPKrLwN+8zenK3vzXIaSCgla4LGdCSqwjHiLIqi-N8JiKex1Heq9ByJIzrBZbV0yisumyAsCNrVo8ny8Y6kIYrAJKqayjmcSW8ZCGquqtxanm5qH1eq8dPi5pT4PVtPaR0zoH7uhat6NYfpaxDVDHIcMkZv5BgQQoJQ8ZEzJlTJmbMpgv5NC8AWWBEBiyKV3jTJUZQgA)